# how to download private file from s3 bucket using java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

1. I tried to open the S3 signed URL in next tab and download the file using window.open().
2. I also tried to get the file content using the InpustStraeam.
3. I also tried getObjectStream to get the object.

But, none of them worked for me.

```
     String existingBucketName = "<your Bucket>";
  String keyName = "/"+"";

  AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(
    DownloadUploadedFile.class
      .getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties")));

  GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(existingBucketName,
    keyName);
  S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(request);
  S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
  IOUtils.copy(objectContent, new FileOutputStream("D://upload//test.jpg"));

 }
```

above is my code

my requirement is :

i want to dowload file from s3 bucket to local sysytem folder

ex: x person wants to download image : that will be stored in x person system folder

Comment: can you include the code, along with a stack trace? see how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mike Tung, I have included the code please check